# Syncing with the apple iCalendar service using java?

Tags: java, synchronization, icloud, icalendar

I have a web app written in Java. Part of the application's intended functionality is adding and and receiving calendar entries from apple's iCalendar service (the calendar that is attached to an apple account that can be displayed on an iOS device and mac computer). I was wondering what library or api that I should be looking at, as there seems to be a general lack of information available on how to accomplish the task.